# Messed up text in browsers

Tags: browser

So for a couple of weeks, I've been having a problem with my text on my browsers. It happens on all of my browsers, but only on some websites, not all. Look at the picture:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried upgrading my graphics card, as well as Adobe Flash. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Can you try pressing Ctrl and - on your keyboard at the same time? (Thinking it's just zoom). Otherwise, what OS are you running?

Comment: yeah, i've tried the zoom but it's already at default. I run windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that it only occurs with some websites, and not with any apps besides web browsers, suggests it is a problem with specific fonts on your system. The Yahoo homepage lists these as its fonts: `"Helvetica Neue",​Helvetica,​Arial`. Helvetica and Helvetica Neue are not usually installed on Windows. Most likely you installed one of these fonts and it is replacing the fallback of Arial, which is always present in Windows.

Try opening Word or OpenOffice or such and using the font dialog to see what is on your system.